# Pandas df data flattenting

Tags: pandas, flatten

I have a pandas df with 3 columns.
contact as col1, profile as col2 and client as col3
Input df as below-

I have tried the answer by mozway but came across 1 more scenario where institute is None.Added that scenario too in my input

```
                                           contact                                               profile                                                                                                                                                           client
    0  {'id': '1', 'name': 'abc', 'country': 'US'}          {'email': 'abc@gmail.com', 'status': 'good'}                                                 {'type': '1', 'code': 'aa', 'institutes': [{'institueid': '1', 'institutename': 'mock1'}], 'sourcecode': '1111'}
    1  {'id': '2', 'name': 'xyz', 'country': 'US'}  {'email': 'hello@gmail.com', 'status': 'inprogress'}  {'type': '2', 'code': 'bb', 'institutes': [{'institueid': '2', 'institutename': 'mock2'}, {'institueid': '4', 'institutename': 'mock3'}], 'sourcecode': '2222'}
    3 {'id': '3', 'name': 'xxx', 'country': 'US'}  {'email': 'hello1@gmail.com', 'status': 'inprogress'}  {'type': '3', 'code': 'bb', 'institutes': None, 'sourcecode': '2222'}
```

expected output

````
    ```
    
      id name country            email      status type code institueid institutename sourcecode
    0  1  abc      US    abc@gmail.com        good    1   aa          1         mock1       1111
    1  2  xyz      US  hello@gmail.com  inprogress    2   bb          2         mock2       2222
    2  2  xyz      US  hello@gmail.com  inprogress    2   bb          4         mock3       2222
    3  3  xxx      US  hello@gmail.com  inprogress    3   bb          None         None      2222

```
````

Reproducible input:

````
    ```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "contact": [
                {"id": "1", "name": "abc", "country":"US"},
                {"id": "2", "name": "xyz", "country":"US"},
                {"id": "3", "name": "xxx", "country":"US"}
            ],
            "profile": [
                {"email": "abc@gmail.com", "status": "good"},
                {"email": "hello@gmail.com", "status": "inprogress"},
                {"email": "hello1@gmail.com", "status": "inprogress"}
            ],
            "client": [
                {
                    "type": "1",
                    "code": "aa",
                    "institutes": [{"institueid": "1", "institutename": "mock1"}],
                    "sourcecode": "1111"
                },
                {
                    "type": "2",
                    "code": "bb",
                    "institutes": [
                        {"institueid": "2", "institutename": "mock2"},
                        {"institueid": "4", "institutename": "mock3"},
                    ],
                    "sourcecode": "2222"
                },
    {
                    "type": "3",
                    "code": "bb",
                    "institutes": None,
                    "sourcecode": "2222"
                }
            ],
        }
    )

```
````

Comment: You input is unclear, please provide a valid python object, also provide the exact matching expected output

Comment: I have updated the input and output both

Comment: Can you please [provide the input as DataFrame constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464)? It's annoying to have to craft the example from text.

Comment: Also, have you tried my approach? Any feedback?

Comment: Yes, I have tried your approach. It works. I need to double check after adding all columns in meta if the result is coming out fine.Thanks so much mozway

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. If you have a chance, can you provide the dataframe constructor of the input? This will add value to the question

Comment: mozway, i was initailly getting issues after adding all columns using your previous answer. Now using your updated response, works fine. Though still need to check the output throughly as there are more than 128 columns. Thanks so much for this.I have been stuck with this for 2 days and i am new to python.I also get a warning 'Data Frame is highly fragmented.This is usually the result frame.insert many times.consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.To get a defragmented frame, use new_frame = frame.copy()"

Comment: Glad it works. keep in mind that my approach considers that only one type of record is nested (`institutes`), if you have a more complex case, then you can consider explaining first how this is different and if too different opening a new question.

Comment: You can ignore the warning for now, it could be due to many things (including previous code of yours), if really you have performance issue that could also be a different question.

Comment: mozway, while validating input, came across another scenario where institutes : None.How can we handle this. Because we the current answer this record gets missed in output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) and [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
from collections import ChainMap

s = df.agg(lambda x: dict(ChainMap(*x)), axis=1)
meta = list(set(s.iloc[0].keys())-{'institutes'})
# ['code', 'country', 'email', 'id', 'name', 'sourcecode', 'status', 'type']

# add missing records
for d in s.loc[s.str['institutes'].isna()]:
    d['institutes'] = [{}]

out = pd.json_normalize(s, record_path='institutes', meta=meta)
```

Output:

```
  institueid institutename type sourcecode country             email code id      status name
0          1         mock1    1       1111      US     abc@gmail.com   aa  1        good  abc
1          2         mock2    2       2222      US   hello@gmail.com   bb  2  inprogress  xyz
2          4         mock3    2       2222      US   hello@gmail.com   bb  2  inprogress  xyz
3        NaN           NaN    3       2222      US  hello1@gmail.com   bb  3  inprogress  xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "contact": [
            {"id": "1", "name": "abc"},
            {"id": "2", "name": "xyz"},
        ],
        "profile": [
            {"email": "abc@gmail.com", "status": "good"},
            {"email": "hello@gmail.com", "status": "inprogress"},
        ],
        "client": [
            {
                "type": "1",
                "code": "aa",
                "institutes": [{"institueid": "1", "institutename": "mock1"}],
                "sourcecode": "1111",
            },
            {
                "type": "2",
                "code": "bb",
                "institutes": [
                    {"institueid": "2", "institutename": "mock2"},
                    {"institueid": "4", "institutename": "mocl3"},
                ],
                "sourcecode": "2222",
            },
        ],
    }
)

for col in df.columns:
    df = pd.concat([df.drop([col], axis=1), df[col].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df = df.explode("institutes")
df = pd.concat([df.drop(["institutes"], axis=1), df["institutes"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

print(df)
```

The output is

```
  id name            email      status  ... code sourcecode institueid institutename
0  1  abc    abc@gmail.com        good  ...   aa       1111          1         mock1
1  2  xyz  hello@gmail.com  inprogress  ...   bb       2222          2         mock2
1  2  xyz  hello@gmail.com  inprogress  ...   bb       2222          4         mocl3
```

Comment: Correction to the input i gave, there are few keys which exact same value.Added 'country_code' above. When i try to explode 'institutes' i get value error that duplicate columns must be unique.

Comment: AKS your approach works but i am not able to explode("institutes"). I get ValeError: Data frame columns must be unique.Duplicate columns :Countrycode  This happens for other columns too which have duplicate values as i have not listed the entire data in the columns in the input have given